# MessageBox API causes access violation and crashes when MB_ICONWARNING is used in combination of MB_OK

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

i have a legacy MFC application built using VS2005, i migrated it to VS2015, on Windows-10 the application works fine, but when testing on Windows-7, the application crashes whenever it has show a Message box, i found that Application does not crash if i remove the ICONWARNING, even tired with other flags which has icon like MB_ICONERROR, i see crash with this also.
The module is a DLL and not an exe.

```
MessageBox(NULL,_T("Something"),_T("Some title"),MB_ICONWARNING|MB_OK); //crashes 
MessageBox(NULL,_T("Something"),_T("Some title"),MB_OK); //No Crash
```

```
Stack trace from the memory dump.
003ce974 7789fb56 00000000 00000000 776f6a2c ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0xbd
003ce99c 748a5ea6 749cc618 0060e248 0060e240 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x150
003ce9b0 748a6000 0060e248 00020021 003ceaac comctl32!CImageList::_Destroy+0x51
003ce9cc 748a61e7 00000030 00000030 00020021 comctl32!CImageList::_Initialize+0x1b
003ce9f4 748da1fc 0060e260 00000030 00000030 comctl32!CImageList::Initialize+0x30
003cea38 748c8239 00a10253 00000028 00000028 comctl32!CreateSmallerIcon+0x9f
003cea68 7490f79c 02840001 00000054 00000028 comctl32!LoadIconWithScaleDown+0x109
003ceab4 74887fb2 0060a352 00000000 00000081 comctl32!CStatic::LoadImageW+0x10f
003ceb2c 7489780c 0005034e 00000001 00000000 comctl32!CStatic::WndProc+0x1bd
003ceb50 770086ef 0005034e 00000001 00000000 comctl32!CStatic::s_WndProc+0x8b
003ceb7c 770079cc 748977cd 0005034e 00000001 user32!InternalCallWinProc+0x23
003cebf4 770070f4 005a334c 748977cd 0005034e user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0xe0
003cec50 77000b5f 00c79278 00000001 00000000 user32!DispatchClientMessage+0xda
003cec80 778b642e 003cec98 00000060 003cf39c user32!__fnINLPCREATESTRUCT+0x8b
003cecf4 77000d69 77000cfd 00000004 0000c019 ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcher+0x2e
003cecf8 77000cfd 00000004 0000c019 003ced48 user32!NtUserCreateWindowEx+0xc
003cef9c 76ff9a8a 00000004 0000c019 003ceff8 user32!VerNtUserCreateWindowEx+0x1a3
003cf078 77025500 76ff0000 00090346 00000000 user32!InternalCreateDialog+0xa4a
003cf0a8 7704e135 76ff0000 0060a2e0 00000000 user32!InternalDialogBox+0xa7
003cf14c 7704e6b9 00000030 68fdf948 00000000 user32!SoftModalMessageBox+0x68a
003cf29c 7704e7ec 003cf2a8 00000028 00000000 user32!MessageBoxWorker+0x2ca
003cf304 7704ea68 00000000 00607c80 00607de0 user32!MessageBoxTimeoutW+0x7f
003cf324 7704eb04 00000000 00607c80 00607de0 user32!MessageBoxExW+0x1b
003cf340 68f31dbf 00000000 00607c80 00607de0 user32!MessageBoxW+0x45
```

MODULE_NAME: comctl32

IMAGE_NAME:  comctl32.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4a5bd976

STACK_COMMAND:  dt ntdll!LdrpLastDllInitializer BaseDllName ; dt ntdll!LdrpFailureData ; ~0s ; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_WRITE_c0000005_comctl32.dll!CImageList::_Destroy

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_CLASS_PTR_WRITE_NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE_INVALID_POINTER_WRITE_comctl32!CImageList::_Destroy+51

FAILURE_EXCEPTION_CODE:  c0000005

FAILURE_IMAGE_NAME:  comctl32.dll

BUCKET_ID_IMAGE_STR:  comctl32.dll

FAILURE_MODULE_NAME:  comctl32

BUCKET_ID_MODULE_STR:  comctl32

FAILURE_FUNCTION_NAME:  CImageList::_Destroy

BUCKET_ID_FUNCTION_STR:  CImageList::_Destroy

BUCKET_ID_OFFSET:  51

BUCKET_ID_MODTIMEDATESTAMP:  4a5bd976

BUCKET_ID_MODCHECKSUM:  1a1908

BUCKET_ID_MODVER_STR:  6.10.7600.16385

BUCKET_ID_PREFIX_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_CLASS_PTR_WRITE_NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE_INVALID_POINTER_WRITE_

FAILURE_PROBLEM_CLASS:  APPLICATION_FAULT

FAILURE_SYMBOL_NAME:  comctl32.dll!CImageList::_Destroy

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/ABT.exe/2.9.13.7/6110c135/ntdll.dll/6.1.7600.16385/4a5bdadb/c0000005/0002fc47.htm?Retriage=1

TARGET_TIME:  2021-08-10T10:52:43.000Z

OSBUILD:  7600

OSSERVICEPACK:  16385

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x86

OSNAME:  Windows 7

OSEDITION:  Windows 7 WinNt SingleUserTS

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2009-07-14 06:39:01

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  090713-1255

BUILDLAB_STR:  win7_rtm

BUILDOSVER_STR:  6.1.7600.16385

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  f8b

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:null_class_ptr_write_c0000005_comctl32.dll!cimagelist::_destroy

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {b3bc3c2c-d915-6f2d-661c-984cc3a945f1}

```
Thank you for looking to this, appreciate any inputs or suggestions.
```

Comment: Could be a bug in comctl32. Can you reproduce with a minimal reproducible project (should be few lines of code)? If yes post it here and report to Microsoft, otherwise, your code may be messing with the memory for some reason and indirectly cause crash.

Comment: I guess that the internal image list is already destroyed or memory is corrupted in some way.  Try to use  _CrtCheckmemory... it may help. Remember that even using MB_ICON flag you get an Icon in the message box. But the warning icon seams to be corrupt in some way. Try to locate the situation after that happens in setting the code that causes the crash in different locations.

Comment: Maybe unrelated to your problem, but when calling `MessageBox()` with a `NULL` parent (usually in a DLL), it is advisable to include the `MB_TASKMODAL` flag in order to achieve modal behaviour, otherwise the message-box won't be blocking the application's UI items. Otherwise, I would try setting the target platform option (although I think Win7 is not included in the last VS versions). Or maybe try explicitly loading the system DLL that contains these icons in Win7. Strange though, as `MessageBox()` is an API-level function.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your inputs , it was indeed an issue with the Windows-7 that i was running on a VM, tried on a another machine and don't see any crash.